# Set socket to UDP in rospy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone tell me how to set UDP socket in service based client server code in ros ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264182/set-socket-to-udp-in-rospy/) by [shantanu543](https://answers.ros.org/users/30523/shantanu543/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rospy does not support the unreliable (UDP) transport. ( http://answers.ros.org/question/28322/unreliable-udp-transport-hints-in-rospy-and-rosjava/ ).

If you want to use a raw UDP socket in your node to communicate with some other, non-ROS UDP device, you'll need to write raw sockets code (or find a different library to wrap your UDP sockets)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shantanu543](https://answers.ros.org/users/30523/shantanu543/) on 2017-06-20**:
can you provide me some reference link or some github project where I can get idea about it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-20**:
an idea about what?

**Comment by [shantanu543](https://answers.ros.org/users/30523/shantanu543/) on 2017-06-20**:
I meant how to write raw sockets code.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-20**:
I learned from one of my college courses; our textbook was [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-20**:
There are a bunch of tutorials online as well, but I haven't tried them so I can't recommend a specific tutorial. A [google search for linux sockets programming](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+sockets+programming&oq=linux+sockets+programming) turns up quite a few.